# Automate collection of data from outlook .msg files to excel field

Tags: excel, outlook, report, msg

My firewall sends me a notifcation to my email every time a policy is violated.

I have about 2500 emails in .msg format that I want to put into one excel document.

Basically I am looking for a way to automate processing each .msg file and putting it on a new line in an excel document.

All 2500+ .msg files are in a single folder.

I understand that .msg files hold binary data, and thats ok. I can clean up the excel document once it is created.

Thanks,
Aaron

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Outlook MSG file format specification](http://www.fileformat.info/format/outlookmsg/).

You should consider getting the messages in some other format that is easier to parse.

Answer (score 0):

Redemption or the Aspose libs can help you out here. There is also [Sean Curries](http://www.outlookcode.com/codedetail.aspx?id=1561) script.